# Disable woocommerce product search plugin's autocomplete

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to disable woocommerce product search autocomplete feature?

Comment: You mean the `seach box` at the yellow bar? Because the bigger one, on that url doesn't have an autocomplete.

Comment: No, I mean the bigger one and yes it does have an autocomplete. Try something "tesco" and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding this bit of jQuery code, for example at your `footer.php`, right before the `</body>` tag closure:

```
<script>
    $('input.field').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
</script>
```

Or the same thing but with pure JavaScript:

```
<script>
var x = document.querySelectorAll("input.search-field");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].autocomplete="off"
}
</script>
```

This will add `autocomplete="off"` for all the search-boxes with the class `.search-field` on your document, which I think all of them have. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/qsuwtgad/).

---

You could implement it directly where the search-box is situated (`header.php`), but you would need to recreate the search-box, because it's implemented dynamically like this - `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` inside the file `header.php`. So you would need to replace that code, with something like this:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://detergentingredients.com/">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" title="Search for:" autocomplete="off"/>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thats great. 

Can you please also help with the main search box in the body of the site. I want to turn off autocomplete of this one also.

Comment: That's interesting, I can swear I saw an `autocomplete="off"` on the src code for that bigger one yesterday. @NaumanTanwir I just realized that all the search boxes have the same class: `.search-field`, so if you implement that updated jQuery code I gave you, it will turn autocomplete off for all the search boxes on the website.